# Is there a tool that generates HTML/CSS code to overlay a shape on a jpeg image?

Tags: html, css

Consider I have an image of a sitting room with a TV. I want to mask the TV with a a simple 2d shape (like a white square) that appears on the image using HTML/CSS.

If the TV is on coordinates ([200,300],[150,400]), the square shape should be on the same coordinates to hide the TV.

Is there a tool or web page that **automates** this procedure, so I can **simply supply an image and define the shape somehow**, and it generates the HTML/CSS code for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little too vague. What shape? Where does it come from? Where does it overlay on the image?

Answer (score 3):

you need something like [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) ?

```
img {
  clip-path: polygon(0px 208px, 146.5px 207px, 147px 141.2px, ...);
}
```

Comment: How can I automate this procedure? I mean a drag and drop wizard without the need of specifying pixels?

Comment: likely use jsб as long as it is common here is an example

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Do you mean JavaScript 6?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator: a drag-and-drop wizard, in HTML and CSS? That’s not really what HTML and CSS do.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Some websites generate desired HTML/CSS codes. That was what I meant. like this one : www.stripegenerator.com/

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator:, ah, gotcha. I’ve edited your question to (hopefully) be a bit clearer about what you actually want.